# Rails + Unicorn + Nginx error (504 Gateway timeout)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

Am struggling to resolve '504 gateway timeout' issue on my rails website on Digitalocean. I started facing this error after I reset my root password for DO droplet.

Please see the unicorn.log below

```
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/rails/first_app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/rails/first_app/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
from /home/rails/first_app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/rails/first_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
from /home/rails/first_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from config.ru:4:in `require_relative'
from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from config.ru:1:in `new'
from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/unicorn-5.3.0/lib/unicorn.rb:56:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/unicorn-5.3.0/lib/unicorn.rb:56:in `block in builder'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/unicorn-5.3.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:796:in `build_app!'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/unicorn-5.3.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:661:in `init_worker_process'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/unicorn-5.3.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:683:in `worker_loop'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/unicorn-5.3.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:549:in `spawn_missing_workers'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/unicorn-5.3.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:563:in `maintain_worker_count'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/unicorn-5.3.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:293:in `join'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/unicorn-5.3.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
E, [2017-12-27T21:10:44.611839 #20975] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 2628 exit 1> worker=1
I, [2017-12-27T21:10:44.611988 #20975]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2017-12-27T21:10:44.614844 #2640]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=2640
I, [2017-12-27T21:10:44.638040 #2640]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
```

and here is my nginx/error.log

```
2017/12/27 21:11:15 [error] 21320#0: *14 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 106.203.174.245, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock/", host: "mysite.com"
```

Please let me know what details should I share, and how can I go about fixing this issue.

Many thanks.

[Edit after comment]

Here is the result for ps -ef | grep unicorn

```
root     20975     1  0 Dec27 ?        00:01:45 unicorn master -D -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production                                                                                         `rails    24881 20975 15 03:16 ?        00:00:00 unicorn worker[0] -D -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production`                                                                                              
rails    24884 20975  0 03:16 ?        00:00:00 unicorn worker[1] -D -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production                                                                                              
root     24887 20975  0 03:16 ?        00:00:00 unicorn worker[2] -D -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production                                                                                              
root     24890 20975  0 03:16 ?        00:00:00 unicorn worker[3] -D -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production                                                                                              
prativi+ 24894 24669  0 03:16 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto unicorn
```

[New edit]

sudo nano /etc/unicorn.conf

```
listen "unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock"
worker_processes 4
user "rails"
working_directory "/home/rails/first_app"
pid "/var/run/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
```

sudo nano etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 60s;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##
            #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # nginx-passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
        ##

        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

PS: I could not locate config/unicorn.rb in my rails app.

Comment: It seems that your unicorn processes did not start correctly. Can you share the result of `ps -ef | grep unicorn` on your server?

Comment: Thanks for the revert. Here is the result for

Comment: @yeuem1vannam Thanks for the revert. Please see the result in the question.

Comment: in this case, it probably that your unicorn is running with the wrong configuration, please add your `nginx.conf` and the unicorn's config file that you thought it was. For Rails app, it usually is `config/unicorn.rb` file.

Comment: @yeuem1vannam I have added nginx.conf & unicorn.conf (could not locate config/unicorn.rb) in the question as requested. Looking forward. Thnaks

Comment: Your current situation that your NginX configuration is wrong for a Rails app using NginX-unicorn stack. Please refer to [Digital Ocean document](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) about the deployment. Be aware about the NginX's **upstream** configuration

Comment: Another way you can do is refer to the [deployment guide of GoRails](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04) The Phusion Passenger seems easier for you.